# Probability of forming a group from three groups

Tags: probability, permutations

I am studying the fundamentals of probability and i encountered this question :
Three groups of children contain respectively 3 girls and 1 boy; 2 girls and 2 boys; 1 girl and 3 boys.

One child is selected at random from each group. Find the probability that the selected consist of 1 girl and 2 boys.

---

I solved like this:
There are 3 arrangements
`GBB` ,`BGB` and `BBG` .

For GBB p1= `9/32`= `3/4` *`2/4` *`3/4`.

For BGB p2= `3/32` =`1/4` *`2/4` *`3/4`

For BBG p3= `1/32` = `1/4` *`2/4` *`1/4`

So total = p1+p2+p3 = 13/32.

But I am having difficulty in  understanding how we account for common events like in both GBB and BGB , we are selecting boy from the third group.
How do we account for that?
If so, is my answer incorrect?

Comment: An event, here, consists of a triple $(C_1, C_2, C_3)$ where $C_i$ is a child selected from group $i$. These events are mutually exclusive so adding the probabilities is fine.